# Courier authentication library not found: compiling courier-imap on Ubuntu Natty

Tags: courier

I am attempting to compile courier-imap on Ubuntu Natty in order to change compiled-in options.  Even though Courier is installed in the system, including the courier-authlib package (using apt-get), `./configure` stops with the following warnings:

```
configure: WARNING: === Courier authentication library not found.
configure: WARNING: === You need to download and install
configure: WARNING: === http://www.courier-mta.org/download.php#authlib first.
configure: WARNING: === If courier-authlib is installed in a non-default
configure: WARNING: === directory, set the COURIERAUTHCONFIG environment
configure: WARNING: === variable to the full path to the courierauthconfig
configure: WARNING: === binary and rerun this configure script.
```

I find `/usr/bin/courier-config` and `/usr/bin/couriertls` binaries and courier libraries in `/usr/lib/courier-authlib/`, but I cannot find a binary named `courierauthconfig`.  Is it necessary to compile and install the courier authentication library even though it has already been installed by apt-get?

Comment: See. You can avoid this all by installing Dovecot.

Comment: This turned out to be the best solution for me.  I abandoned Courier and set up Dovecot instead.  Since I abandoned the problem that prompted my original question, I can neither vote the one proposed answer up nor down.

Comment: You can still post your comment as answer and accept that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the appropriate source (dev) packages, too. Otherwise you can't compile against them and have only the binary part installed.

But I can only discourage you from installing software from sources. You then need to maintain them and integrate security fixes into your software regularly. Meaning you have to always follow official security reports (e.g. CVEs). Your distribution's package maintainer already does it for your packages.